# How do I save results of a "for" loop into a single variable?

Tags: python, loops

I have a `for` loop:

```
for x in range(1, 13):
    print("This was the average temperature in month number " + str(x) + " in Boston, 2014: ", Boston_monthly_temp(x))
```

This prints out the average monthly temperatures in Boston in 2014, such as:

```
This was the average temperature in month number 1 in Boston, 2014:  26.787096774193547
```

all the way up until Month Number 12 (December):

```
This was the average temperature in month number 12 in Boston, 2014:  38.42580645161291.
```

All in all, this for loop produces 12 lines.

However, I can't figure out how to store the results of this "for" loop into a single variable, like `output_number_one`.

Comment: Since 'saving to a variable', you can ditch the `print` (because it is used for a side-effect and not value generation) in which case a [List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) would be an idiomatic approach (the link also shows how to explicitly build a list).

Answer (score 15):

Try this

```
result = []
for x in range(1,13):
    result.append((x, Boston_monthly_temp(x)))
```

Now `result` contains the `x` and `avg`

```
>>> for x, avg in result:
...     print ("This was the average temperature in month number " + str(x) + " in Boston, 2014: ", avg)
...
This was the average temperature ...
This was the average temperatu ...
[...]
```

Answer (score 5):

You could simply store the results in a dictionary:

```
d = {}
for x in range(1,13):
   d[x] = Boston_monthly_temp(x)
```