# How to read API JSON data and store as Python dictionary

Tags: python, json, loops, dictionary

I am pulling in info from an API. The returned data is in JSON format. I have to iterate through and get the same data for multiple inputs. I want to save the JSON data for each input in a python dictionary for easy access. This is what I have so far:

```
import pandas
import requests

ddict = {}

read_input = pandas.read_csv('input.csv')
for d in read_input.values:
    print(d)
    url = "https://api.xyz.com/v11/api.json?KEY=123&LOOKUP={}".format(d)
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.json()
    ddict[d] = data

df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(ddict, orient='index')

with pandas.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as w:
    df.to_excel(w, 'output')
```

With the above code, I get the following output:

```
    a.com
```

I also get an excel output with the data only from this first line. My input csv file has close to 400 rows so I should be seeing more than 1 line in the output and in the output excel file.

If you have a better way of doing this, that would be appreciated. In addition, the excel output I get is very hard to understand. I want to read the JSON data using dictionaries and subdictionaries but I don't completely understand the format of the underlying data - I think it looks closest to a JSON array.

I have looked at numerous other posts including [Parsing values from a JSON file using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835559/parsing-values-from-a-json-file-in-python) and [How do I write JSON data to a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309269/how-do-i-write-json-data-to-a-file-in-python) and [Converting JSON String to Dictionary Not List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483351/converting-json-string-to-dictionary-not-list-python) and [How do I save results of a "for" loop into a single variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29225619/how-do-i-save-results-of-a-for-loop-into-a-single-variable) but none of the techniques have worked so far. I would prefer not to pickle, if possible.

I'm new to Python so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not going to address your challenges with JSON here as I'll need more information on the issues you're facing. However, with respect to reading from CSV using Pandas, here's a great resource: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html.

Now, your output is being read the way it is because `a.com` is being considered the header (undesirable). Your read statement should be:

```
read_input = pandas.read_csv('input.csv', header=None)
```

Now, read_input is a DataFrame ([documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas.DataFrame)). So, what you're really looking for is the values in the first column. You can easily get an array of values by `read_input.values`. This gives you a separate array for each row. So your for loop would be:

```
for d in read_input.values:
    print(d[0])
    get_info(d[0])
```

For JSON, I'd need to see a sample structure and your desired way of storing it.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a awkwardness in you program.

Try with this:

```
ddict = {}
read_input = pandas.read_csv('input.csv')
for d in read_input.values:
    url = "https://api.xyz.com/v11/api.json?KEY=123&LOOKUP={}".format(d)
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.json()
    ddict[d] = data
```

Edit: iterate the `read_input.values`.

Comment: I made that edit but the code is still not iterating through the csv file.