# How to assign printed results to a new variable when it comes to looping?

Tags: python, loops, variables, printing

I have the code and its output. I need to save the printed results by assigning them to a new variable.

```py
for n in range(1,11):
            ticket= f"ticket number {n}"
            print(ticket)
```

Output:

```
ticket number 1
ticket number 2
ticket number 3
ticket number 4
ticket number 5
ticket number 6
ticket number 7
ticket number 8
ticket number 9
ticket number 10
```

I also tried to use `results = []`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I save results of a "for" loop into a single variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29225619/how-do-i-save-results-of-a-for-loop-into-a-single-variable)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
results = [f"ticket number {n}" for n in range(1, 11)]
```

Final result contains:

```
['ticket number 1', 'ticket number 2', 'ticket number 3', 'ticket number 4', 'ticket number 5', 'ticket number 6', 'ticket number 7', 'ticket number 8', 'ticket number 9', 'ticket number 10']
```